# Cross Origin Resource Sharing Issue with jQuery on https secure url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, cors

I'm having a slight issue with a cross site origin request. I'm sure it is a simple fix.

Console error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://subdomain.example.com/social/disqus. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

js script causing the issue:

```
window.onload = function(){
  //jQuery AJAX GET Method on Disqus Threads
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://subdomain.example.com/social/disqus',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

    success: function(threads) {
      var len = Object.keys(threads.response).length
      for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (threads.response[i].posts == 0 || threads.response[i].posts != 1) {
          $('#' + threads.response[i].identifiers).html(threads.response[i].posts + " Comments ");
        } else {
          $('#' + threads.response[i].identifiers).html(threads.response[i].posts + " Comment ");
        }
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("Aw, snap!");
    }
  });
};
```

I'm forcing redirects in Apache for both - this may be an issue, but it looks like the CORS request is being fired from a https:// valid site to another https:// valid site... url in the ajax request is *definitely* https.

I'm wondering if I am missing something from `$.ajax` ?

Comment: You need to implement CORS headers and handling of OPTIONS requests server side

Comment: A setting within Apache?

Comment: What programming language are you using server side? Also please note that implementing CORS is extremely easily searched on the web. There is even a whole site dedicated to it

Comment: Hi. Yeh found what the issue is. I had permission from https://www.example.com to get requests but I didn’t need to specify a contentType in the AJAX get request.

Comment: FWIW: Django (Python)